# Problems with libconfig PKG_CONFIG_PATH enviroment variable

Tags: 12.04, gcc, libraries

I've coded a project with some files in C. To make it easy for the user to start the program I started to generate a cfg-file. For this reason I installed libconf. Unfortunately on compiling with a example file of libconfig I get this message.

```
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libconfig) example1.c -o example1 example.cfg



example1.c: In Function »main«: example1.c:43:13: Warning: Format »%s« expected argumenttyp »char *«, but argument 3   has typ »int« [-Wformat]

.....
```

As I got told I installed **sudo apt-get install libconfig8-dev** and was hoping not setting up any PKG_CONFIG_PATH. It looks like it's not compiling correct.

Comment: I found that the .pc files are stored in /usr/lib/pkgconfig but how can I set it up in the enviroment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH

Comment: It is a malformed idea to think that you have to set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to fix this problem. Fendrix, you do not have to do that. The error message is a bit misleading. You should read my answer.

Comment: I just put the command gcc `pkg-config --cflags libconfig` configTest.c -o configTest and it compiled.... hope it runs ... if so thank u very much allquixotic

Comment: I would suggest revising your compile command as follows: `gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libconfig` configTest.c -o configTest`

Comment: Err, `gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libconfig) configTest.c -o configTest`

Comment: Warnings are non-fatal, which means that the application can *definitely* still compile, and *probably* still run correctly, with the warning. Errors are fatal. Do you get compile errors?

Comment: I found out that the example1.c an sample from the libconfig is not compiling but the file sample1.c from the /usr/share/doc/libconfig8-dev/examples compiles without problems ... both are in the same folder... example1 doesn't find some functions just like config_error_file even it is in the libconfig

Comment: I presume the file example1.c is not correctly coded even it is an example file of libconfig.... undefined reference to `config_error_file'... even doc says this function exists... close it answered... will have a look at it tomorrow... if no solution is found I ll post it to stackoverflow as this is definite not a compiling fault and so this topic is done... thanks allquixotic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you obtain and install `libconfig`?

If you just installed the `libconfig8` package, that is **not enough**. You also need to install the `-dev` package corresponding to it, in order to provide the development files (headers, static link library, and pkg-config data). I was able to find that for libconfig for precise on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libdevel/libconfig8-dev). So

`sudo apt-get install libconfig8-dev`

should do the trick.

As you can see from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/libconfig8-dev/filelist), the file list for this package contains the following file path:

`/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libconfig.pc`

This is precisely the file that `pkg-config` needs to be able to pull out the `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` corresponding to `libconfig`.

This directory is on the "built-in' `pkg-config` search path out of the box on Ubuntu. For this reason, it is not necessary to set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`. You would only ever set that environment variable if you need `pkg-config` to look in directories **other than** those which it searches by default. So if you compiled a program and installed it in `/home/user/apps/blah` and the file `/home/user/apps/blah/lib/pkg-config/libblah.pc` needed to be available to `pkg-config`, you would set:

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/user/apps/blah/lib/pkg-config/libblah.pc`

to make `pkg-config` find that installation of `libblah.pc`.

However, since you are installing `libconfig` from Ubuntu itself, it will automatically "plunk" the .pc file in the correct search directory.

Comment: thanks a lot... nearly got it ... now I don't get the enviroment error message any more but still on compiling gcc `pkg-config --cflags libconfig` configTest.c -o configTest pkg-config --libs libconfig... it says pkg-config not found libconfig not found and --libs not recognized

Comment: Please edit your original question indicating the exact input you get, and the output. Also be aware that the second call to `pkg-config` in your command line needs to be in backticks (`) or in a $() statement.